# Reducing a Postgres table to JSON

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a following table in Postgres

```
+----+-----------+----------------------+---------+
| id |    user_fk|  language_fk         | details |
+----+-----------+----------------------+---------+
|  1 | 2         | en-us                |  123    |
|  2 | 3         | en-us                |  456    |
|  3 | 4         | en-us                |  789    |
|  4 | 4         | es-la                |  012    |
+----+-----------+----------------------+---------+
```

And I want to reduce this to the following SQL statement:

```
UPDATE users SET details = '{"en-us": "789", "es-la": "012"}' WHERE id = 4;
UPDATE users SET details = '{"en-us": "123"}' WHERE id = 2;
UPDATE users SET details = '{"en-us": "456"}' WHERE id = 3;
```

So I want to reduce languages per user and put it in a different table. Is there a way to do this in Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function [`jsonb_object_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) to get the expected output:

```
select 
    min(id) as id, 
    user_fk, 
    jsonb_object_agg(language_fk, details) as details
from users
group by user_fk

 id | user_fk |             details              
----+---------+----------------------------------
  1 |       2 | {"en-us": "123"}
  2 |       3 | {"en-us": "456"}
  3 |       4 | {"en-us": "789", "es-la": "012"}
(3 rows)
```

You cannot update the table in this way because of different types of old and new `details` column. Create a new table with reduced columns using `create table` from `select:`

```
create table new_users as
select 
    min(id) as id, 
    user_fk, 
    jsonb_object_agg(language_fk, details) as details
from users
group by user_fk;
```

Comment: Thank you! What happens if I have two tables - the old and new users with JSON columns. How do I update it with one query?

Comment: I don't think you need two tables, one of them will be redundant. You may drop the old table and rename the new one. Alternatively, you can add a jsonb column to the existing table. In that case you should dalete duplicated rows for `user_fk` and drop the column `language_fk`.

Comment: I'm migrating data from old table to the new one, but yeah - you saved the day with `jsonb_object_agg()`.